# Show real runtime hyperlink when using asp tag helper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

when I generate a hyperlink with asp-tag helpers it looks like this:

```
<a asp-page="/demo">Demo</a>
```

The html output looks like that:

```
<a href="/test/Demo">Demo</a>
```

But I want to show the user not the hyperlink "Demo" but instead the real address at runtime (localhost:xxxx/test/demo).

The problem ist that at compile time I did not know that. Is there an easy way that the asp-page feature generates me the hyperlink content?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you need to implement your own `AnchorTagHelper` with steps below:

1. Custom `AnchorTagHelper`

   ```
   [HtmlTargetElement("a-link")]
   public class MyAnchorTagHelper : AnchorTagHelper
   {
       private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
       public MyAnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator
           , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(generator)
       {
           _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
       }
       public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
       {
           base.Process(context, output);
           output.TagName = "a";
           var basePath = $"{_httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpContext.Request.Host}{_httpContext.Request.PathBase}";
           TagHelperAttribute href;
           if (output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute("href", out href))
           {
               output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", $"{basePath}{href.Value}");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `MyAnchorTagHelper` in `_ViewImports.cshtml` with `@addTagHelper *, namespace`

   ```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
   @using TestRazor2_2
   @using TestRazor2_2.Data
   @namespace TestRazor2_2.Pages
   @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
   @addTagHelper *, TestRazor2_2
   ```
3. UseCase

   ```
   <a-link href="/test/Demo">Demo</a-link>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want the actual content of the link to be the URL rather than the string "Demo". If that's the case, you'll need to use the `UrlHelper`:

```
<a asp-page="/demo">@Url.Page("/demo")</a>
```

That introduces a bit of duplication, though, so I'd actually suggest doing something like:

```
@{ var demoUrl = Url.Page("/demo"); }
<a href="@demoUrl">@demoUrl</a>
```

If you want an absolute URL, then you need to pass the `scheme` param:

```
Url.Page("/demo", null, null, PageContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme)
```